# How to kill a process running under SYSTEM account in the Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service, kill-process

I have a server with Windows Server 2008 R2 and a service process (our custom service) running on it under SYSTEM account. A service has presumably hanged and I wanted to stop it. I tried stopping via Management Console "Services" snap-in, but it didn't help, service process still running, despite in the Management Console it is already marked as not running. Is there a way to kill it from the command line? Note that service runs under the SYSTEM account. I have full administrative privileges on the server.

I have tried `pskill` from console with elevated privileges (just as `pskill PID`), but it didn't do the job: it has reported that process killed, but I still see it in the Task Manager.

Taskkill also doesn't help:

```
C:\>taskkill /f /im myservice.exe
ERROR: The process "myservice.exe" with PID 1268 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

But the process still visible in the Task Manager.

Update:
Powerhell `Stop-Process -Name myservice -Force` also didn't work.

Any ideas how to really kill the process (except rebooting the server)?

Comment: What about an elevated PowerShell console?  Stop-Process -Name myservice -Force

Comment: `Stop-Process -Name myservice -Force` didn't work as well. The process still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [pstools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) and extract the downloaded zip file.
There will be an exe file with name psexec.

open cmd.exe/command prompt with run as admin option.
There you type below command.
"psexec.exe /s /i cmd.exe"

It will launch one more console window with system user as current user.
From there you can run whatever commands you want with system user access